# Eslint yells that 'path' should be listed in the project's dependencies. But `path` is default by node right?

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

My eslint keeps yelling at me this error message:

```
'path' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S path' to add iteslint(import/no-extraneous-dependencies)
```

I didn't even have a `tsconfig.json` file in my project root, why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: you should use `'./path'` to reference your local files (`'path'` references to node modules and since you are not using such a module you are getting an error)

Comment: Curious if there is a better way to solve this, and if it's something new. I just installed it in my dev dependencies since, in my project, I'm only using it in my webpack config.